# Remove event on children when parent destroyed

Tags: jquery, events, tooltip

I have a html table, and each row has a button to remove the row.
The button has a simple tooltip ('Delete this row ?').

My problem is that when I click on the button, the parent row is destroyed, the button disappears, but the "mouseleave" event on the button isn't triggered and the tooltip stay here forever.

I saw in another thread that there was a "remove" event, that we can use with on().
But it's not working. Do you know if this event exists ?

If not, do you know how i could make this tooltip disappear ?

Here is my code :

```
        $(document).on('mouseenter', '.tooltip-btn', function() {
            if(($('#tooltip').length)==0){
                $('<span id=\"tooltip\">').appendTo('body').hide();
            }
            $('#tooltip').stop(true, true).html($(this).attr('title')).show().position({
                at: 'top-10',
                my: 'bottom',
                of: $(this),
                collision: 'flipfit',
                within: $('#contenu')
            }).hide(0, function(){
                $(this).fadeIn(150);
            });
        }).on('mouseleave', '.tooltip-btn', function() {
            $('#tooltip').stop(true, true).fadeOut(150);
        }).on('remove', '.tooltip-btn', function() {
            alert('I am removed');
        });
```

Thanks...

Comment: You can [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) the `mouseleave` event yourself just before the parent row is destroyed.

Comment: Or call `$('#tooltip').stop(true, true).fadeOut(150);` when the parent row is removed.

Comment: This could work, but I would like to separate the tooltip code and the data code... And if i do that, everytime i need to remove something i'll be forced to check if a children's event needs to be triggered...